# how to make an illusion of 3D image

Tags: html, css

I have image and I want to make it look like 3D. It should be looking like this: [image]

How can I do this? I tried box-shadow but it didn't look like real 3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

border with gradient can do it:

```css
img {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
  border-image-slice: 0 15 15 0; /* same as border-width*/
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, grey 0 calc(100% - 10px), transparent 0);
}

body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/300/200">
```

like below if you want different coloration for a better 3D rendring:

```css
img {
  --t:15px;
  border-right: var(--t) solid grey;
  border-bottom:var(--t) solid #626161;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,calc(100% - var(--t)) 0,100% var(--t),100% 100%,var(--t) 100%,0 calc(100% - var(--t)));
}

body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/300/200">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is yet another approach: use `before` and `after` pseudo-elements with transform.

```css
.whatever
{
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/100/100");
}

.whatever::before
{
  content:"";
  background-color: gray;
  position:relative;
  display: block;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  top: 100px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
}

.whatever::after
{
  content:"";
  background-color: gray;
  position:relative;
  display: block;
  transform: skewY(45deg);
  left: 100px;
  top: -4px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="whatever"></div>
```